# What does a high number of rx_crc_errors indicate?

Tags: ethtool

When running ethtool I notice a very high level of rx_crc_errors. When the server is under heavy load the counter goes even higher. What does this typically point to as the source of the problem? Media or cable issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically errors of this type (errors that indicate bad data integrity) are the result of layer 1 problems. I'd investigate cabling and the physical layer interface first.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try doing the testing you've suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the ethernet cable would be my first step to debug, followed by testing the patch field connectors etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try doing the testing you've suggested.